# Setting the delete button on javascript

Tags: javascript

hello im trying to write this code for add a delete btn for each input, i add each one via javascript with no problem :·

But the delete btn its not working at all, i think you will see my error faster, cause im really a newbie on javascript. hope you can help me..

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var i = $('.field').size() + 1;
    $('#add').click(function () {
        $('<div class="fieldss' + i + '"><label for="link' + i + '">Video/Link</label><input type="text" class="field' + i + '" name="link' + i + '" value="' + i + '" /><a href="#" id="remove' + i + '">Remove</a></div>').fadeIn('slow').appendTo('.inputs');
        i++
    });
    $('#remove' + i + '').click(function () {
        $('.fieldss' + i + '').remove();
        i--
    });
    $('#reset').click(function () {
        while (i > 2) {
            $('.field:last').remove();
            i--
        }
    });
    $('.submit').click(function () {
        var answers = [];
        $.each($('.field'), function () {
            answers.push($(this).val())
        });
        if (answers.length == 0) {
            answers = "none"
        }
        alert(answers);
        return false
    })
});
```

The problem must be in the delete btn code because i didnt know how to set it like this... I use to have it like this, but this delete just the LAST item added and i need a delete btn for each.

```
 $('#reset').click(function () {
     while (i > 2) {
         $('.fieldss:last').remove();
         i--;
     }
 });
```

Comment: When you say "delete btn" do you mean "'remove' link"?

Comment: @Jules Can you post your html mark up too, so that we can help better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are adding it dynamically you can use event delegation binding event to the parent that exists. Use a class `remove` add it to the remove element. Also you can just use `<div class="fieldss">` and then:-

```
$('#add')
        .click(function () {
        $('<div class="fieldss"><label for="link' + i + '">Video/Link</label><input type="text" class="field' + i + '" name="link' + i + '" value="' + i + '" /><a href="#" id="remove' + i + '" class="remove">Remove</a></div>')
            .fadeIn('slow')
            .appendTo('.inputs');
        i++;
    });

$(document).on('click','.remove', function() { 
// use a container selector instead of document.

   $(this).closest('.fieldss').remove();
});
```